# Can I attach an integer variable to a function defined by a macro?

Tags: c++

I want to append an integer variable to a function name using a macro but the following code doesn't work:

```
#define TEST(num) test_##num()

void test_0(void){ /* some code here*/ }

void somefunc(){
   int somevar = 0;
   TEST(somevar);
}
```

This ends up in a call to test_somevar().

I know that you can make an enum of numbers and use that list but i don't want to do this cause it kind of defeats the purpose of what i'm trying to do.

Is there a way to do this efficiently?

Comment: "it kind of defeats the purpose of what i'm trying to do. " What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run time values can't be used/seen by the preprocessor, but you can use an array of functions to do this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    void (*test[1])(void) = { test_0 };
    test[0]();
    return 0;
}
```

Or, given the array, you can define a macro:

```
#define TEST(x) test[x]()
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work unless `somevar` is also a macro.

The reason is because  `TEST(somevar)` is expanded into `TEST_somevar` at preprocessing time (assuming your macro works correctly), while the value of `some_var` is not known until (at least) compile time, if not run time.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do what you want to do is to have an array of function pointers and then have somevar index different tests within that array.